# Typedef with arrays in C

Tags: c, typedef

Hello I am new to C programming. After using python for a long time, C seems infinitely harder (and well infinitely more fun)!

What I cannot wrap my head around is using `typedef` with arrays and in particular 2D Arrays.

```
typedef double vector_t[10];
```

As far as I understand this helps us use `vector_t` to initialise an array of `double`s with 10 elements. So would initialising `vector_t[10]` initialise an Array of `[10][10]`?

Also what if I initialise `vector_t[5]`?

```
typedef vector_t second_t[5];
```

What will happen if I use `second_t`? Will the 2d array be array of `[10][5]` or an array of `[5][10]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use

```
second_t v;
```

That's exactly the same as

```
vector_t v[5];
```

And that's exactly the same as

```
double v[5][10]; /* NOT double[10][5] */
```

When you expand a `typedef`, imagine that you're substituting whatever's after the `typedef` for the `typedef`'s name in its definition:

```
typedef something t[size];
t x;
/* subst [t := x] into the typedef definition */
something x[size];

second_t v;
/* [second_t := v] in definition */
vector_t v[5];
/* [vector_t := v[5]] in definition */
double v[5][10];

typedef int (*unary_op)(int); /* pointers to functions int => int */
typedef int (*consumer)(unary_op); /* pointers to functions (int => int) => int */
consumer f;
/* [consumer := f] in definition */
int (*f)(unary_op);
/* [unary_op := ] (replace unary_op with "", because there's no name) in definition.
   We must respect parentheses */
int (*f)(int (*)(int));
// Something like int func(unary_op op) { return op(5); }
```

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I understand this helps us use vector_t to initialise an array of doubles with 10 elements.

That's not quite correct. To be precise, this typedef defines a custom type which enables one to *declare* an array, say, `vector_t example[N];` which bona fide dimension will be `N + 1` (since `vector_t` already assumes that a single element is itself a 1-dimensional array). Saying *initialise* means that you fill that memory with some data. In this particular case you may say `memset(my_vec, 0, sizeof(my_vec));` to zeroise the array. If you have a simpler variable, say, `int a;`, then you may *initialise* it with, say, `a = 1;`.

If you declare `vector_t another_example[10][10]`, this will actually give you a 3-dimensional array - 10 x 10 x 10.

> what will happen if I use second_t? will the 2d array be Array[10][5] or Array[5][10]??

So, as you might understand from the beginning of my post, in the latter case, neither declaring `second_t Array[10][5]` nor `second_t Array[5][10]` will give a 2D array.
Actually, this will be **4**-dimensional array since `second_t` defines a single element as being already a 2D array.

For educational purposes I suggest that you simply start with something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t vector_t[10];
```

in order to be able to construct more complex types, then declare arrays (say, the variable will be called `array`) and, finally, do something like `printf("The size is %lu bytes\n", sizeof(array));` in order to see the total size in bytes. Then it will be easy to see what the total size is taking into account that the very base type is `uint8_t` (1 byte).